# Asp.net, Access DataBase Hyperlink Datatype not active

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access, hyperlink

I am currently have an ms access database, reading into a table in aspx file in asp.net just fine.

However I want some the the table values to be hyperlinks to other pages.
(The table field data type is set to hyperlink.)

But when I view the webpage the link doesn't active(go blue) so i can't click on it.

Is there way to fix this or an easier way to program it?

Tell me if want see the code and which part you wish to see.

```
webpage.aspx.cs

protected string methodName()
    {
        string string1 = "";
        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder sb = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        sb.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        sb.DataSource = Server.MapPath("/username/uploads/database1.accdb");


        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(sb.ConnectionString);
        string queryString = "";
        OleDbCommand myCmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString, myConnection);
        myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from TableName Order by ID";

        myConnection.Open();

        OleDbDataReader reader = myCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string CName = reader.GetString(1);
            string IName = reader.GetString(2);
            string1 += "<tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + CName + "</td><td>" + IName + "</td></tr>";

        }

        reader.Close();
        myConnection.Close();
        return string1;
}
```

Comment: Show the code in your view and what values are stored in that hyperlink column in database ?

Comment: I don't quite under the first bit, but the database .... Item Name "Item Name"X:\directoryname\webpage1.aspx sorta like that

Comment: Try using a `<asp:HyperLink>` and then setting its `NavigateUrl` property to the value in your database. That should work.

Comment: I've added some of my code perhaps that will help.

Comment: Which one is the hyperlink field? CName or IName ?

Comment: Try replacing the last IName `td` block with this : `<td><a href='"+IName+"'/></td>`

Comment: That made the IName column disappear entirely on the webpage.

Comment: Oops. It should. Try this : `<td><a href='"+IName+"'/>Click Here</td>`

Comment: Apart from the "Click here's" being above the table and not in it... that works. That and the fact that address is adding the table value text to the url and screwing it up...

Comment: That might be due to some CSS issue. Might want to check it out to adjust the spacing in your table so that every link fits fine and doesnt break up the table.

Comment: Would be good if you can update your question showing the table code as well.

Comment: Fixed my url address being wrong in the database, can you put your answer in the "answer your question" form" Oops forgot the opening <td> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that its just plain text and you would need a control there that will help you set up a navigation link ot that text link.
You can try something like this here :

```
<td><a href='"+IName+"'/>Click Here</td>
```

This will setup a anchor link in your page which will navigate to the specified link when clicked.

Hope this helps.